# Opengl render to Depth texture - red color?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm trying to implement shadowmapping, so I'm rendering to depth texture. When I don't bind framebuffer which contains depth texture and use default framebuffer, it outputs to screen. However, instead of white color for distant fragments, they're red.

This is my fragment shader:

```
#version 330 

out float fragmentdepth;
uniform sampler2D inputTex;

void main(){
fragmentdepth = gl_FragCoord.z;
}
```

Is it a problem? Because shadowmapping isn't working and I'd like to rule out this as source of problem.

Comment: If you are writing to a depth texture, why are you outputting the depth to a color buffer? This basically doubles the memory bandwidth requirements for this shader since the depth is *also* written to whatever is attached to your FBO's depth attachment point.

Comment: I can't remember, but `gl_FragDepth` hasn't been dropped like `gl_FragColour` right? This would make sense if `fragmentdepth` is simply being treated as red in an otherwise RGBA output to COLOUR_ATTACHMENT0. Unless you're intending to write depth to a floating point colour texture instead of a depth texture but you'd still need depth testing anyway, which as @AndonM.Coleman points out would be double the bandwidth. Maybe try writing to `gl_FragDepth`?

Comment: Definitely not, `gl_FragDepth` still exists. It is a _very_ bad idea to write anything to it in a shader though, because it breaks a lot of hardware depth optimizations (Hi-Z, early depth tests, etc...).

Comment: Did you get your shadows in the end? Did it matter the depth texture was shaded red?

Answer (score 2):

Depth is a scalar value. Scalar is interpreted by OpenGL as a single component texture. Single component texture means that only the `.x` or `.r` element (whatever you use) gets nonzero.

Comment: When I'm reading from said texture in shader, x, y and z elements are non zero.

Comment: @user1760770 That is because for versions of GLSL >= 130, any sampler2D that has a depth texture bound to it will always return vec4 (r, r, r, 1.0) irrespective of how you set `GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE_MODE` (since it was removed from GL3). This is explained on pg. 320 of the [OpenGL 3.2 core spec](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec32.core.20091207.pdf).